# How to pass IStream* in C++ DLL to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, istream

Now,I call a function,and return a IStream*.in c++ applicaction ,I can use Cimage.load(IStream*),and save it.it is successful.

but in c# ,I cannot get the IStream.

and the iBitMapSize also is short. For example in c++ it's 34257415. in c# it's 342.
the size is.. I get a image from third-party library.the image of class is the author defines it himself. when I use the function of library to get a image, I get image of size to iBitMapSize , then give image to IWICStream , then give IWICStream to IStream*.

c++ application code:

```
     typedef IStream*(*GetRegionTile)(const wchar_t* , int64_t , int64_t , float , int64_t , int64_t, uint64_t&);
     GetRegionTile getregiontile = (GetRegionTile)GetProcAddress(hDllInst, "GetRegionTile");
     IStream* stream= getregiontile(filepath, x,y, _zoom, w, h,  iBitMapSize);
     CImage image;
     image.Load(stream);
     LPCTCH savePath= L"D:/123.png";
     image.Save(savePath, Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG);
```

c# importdll code:

```
     [DllImport("SConver.dll", EntryPoint = "GetRegionTile", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
     public static extern System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream GetRegionTile(string fileName, long x, long y, float zoom, long w, long h, out uint iBitMapSize);
```

c# usedll code:

```
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream = Import_DLL.GetRegionTile(file_name, lx, ly, zoom, lw, lh, out iBitMapSize);
      byte[] fileBytes = new byte[iBitMapSize];
      stream.Read(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
      System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileBytes);
      System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
      image.Save(@"D:\123.png");
```

I am a c# developer, not particularly familiar with c++ foundation. I may ask the basic question, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The last arg of your C# import says `out uint iBitMapSize`, where your original C++ version says `uint64_t&`. Fairly sure that'll need to be `long` too in the C# version.

Comment: yes.I use long .but  it always short.